# How to stop touch event for desired time in android?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to stop touch event for some time. I mean for that time when user touches screen nothing should happen and other functionality remains active. When that time passes user should again be able to touch i.e. now touch functions as it was before. I am looking for a solution in Android Libgdx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this just use [InputProcessor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

To disable input evetns you can use

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
```

To set touch active you need to set input processor again (due to what inputProcessor you have implemented)

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(yourInputProcessor);
```